# Approximating surface area from an image with Python

Tags: python, image, area

I plan to calculate the surface area of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLq7F.png) cone by

1. Splitting the image into top/bottom halves of the cone
2. Finding the brightest spot on top/bottom halves
3. Finding the distance between brightest spots on top/bottom halves as a diameter for every pixel along the x axis and using it to calculate a dS for the total S, surface area

However, [this appears unreliable at the extremities (tip and base)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vez3I.png). How can I make it more reliable at base/tip? or is my approach entirely wrong?

Edit: I want it to truncate in the black space, on both ends

Comment: this seems more like a math than a programming question. Assuming it's a normal cone, I would just find the intersection of the lines defined by the two sides to find the tip

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could create lines-of-best-fit.

Futhermore, how should I define the termination of the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try applying a filter that will make cone pixels white and other pixels black (e.g. provide a binary image). After that the area of the cone is just the sum of the white pixels.

Comment: Can filter's only work with hard-coded threshold values? I'd like it to be flexible with a variety of images that may sometimes only be vaguely similar.

Comment: @user2510173: no, some analysis can be applied before the filter. Such as calculating the histogram of the image and calculating filter parameters based on it

Comment: The histogram idea seems very promising. I'll look into that, and using it in conjunction with a filter to create a definite area.